# it is normal for linux to read a block of size more than 4KB (or several blocks of 4KB each) at a time?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am writing a device driver for a network attached hard drive and my problem is that I can see that Linux is sending requests to my block device that exceed the typical 4KB requests. Actually, the behavior I can notice is that. It sends a request of 4kB first, then the second request is of size 8KB, then 16KB and so on. Is there any way to disable this behavior and limit Linux to send requests of 4KB at a time? or is this something bad in my code?

- How I calculated the request total size: I have the sector size set to 512 bytes. And when I call `blk_rq_sectors` on any request I get the number of sectors stated in that request. Sometimes, I see requests consist of 8, 16, 32, or 64 sectors.

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like Linux is attempting to optimize the network traffic by sending the data in larger size "chunks."  Are you sure you want to discourage this behavior?

Comment: yes, it is causing the driver to block when it gets to large block sizes. Besides, how does Linux sees that I am using the network behind the block device. This fact should be hidden from it.

Comment: @user2009594 it's really hard to tell why it's behaving this way, without seeing the code at all. Also, I'm not much aware of storage networking stuffs. Is there any code that you wrote? Is it your driver behaving this way?

Comment: Here it is https://bitbucket.org/hebbo_pub/networkblockdevice