# How to disable request merges in Block device driver?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

How to disable this feature in a block device driver?
What I mean: as mentioned in the below documentation I want to set the value of that "flag" to 2. Where do I do that? preferably in the block device driver code.

```
What:       /sys/block/<disk>/queue/nomerges
Date:       January 2010
Contact:
Description:
        Standard I/O elevator operations include attempts to
        merge contiguous I/Os. For known random I/O loads these
        attempts will always fail and result in extra cycles
        being spent in the kernel. This allows one to turn off
        this behavior on one of two ways: When set to 1, complex
        merge checks are disabled, but the simple one-shot merges
        with the previous I/O request are enabled. When set to 2,
        all merge tries are disabled. The default value is 0 -
        which enables all types of merge tries.
```

Comment: Search the kernel tree for QUEUE_FLAG_NOMERGES.  The sysfs will set this flag on the request queue when it is set to 2.

Comment: Why would you want to disable it? If your driver does not work correctly with merged requests, it is broken.

Comment: yeah, I know it is broken. I am trying to fix it. That is why I want to disable request merging. I was suspecting that network latency has something to do with it.

Comment: @PeterL. disabling it this way requires kernel recompilation. None of the functions that set that flag is exported.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First check the nomerges value -

```
              cat /sys/block/sda/queue/nomerges
```

if it's not already 2, then do:

```
              echo 2 > /sys/block/sda/queue/nomerges
```

Comment: I tried this, and in fact I could see the value changed to 2. However, I can still see requests of more than 4KBs each. Is there any reason why I see this behavior?

Comment: please my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19574066/it-is-normal-for-linux-to-read-a-block-of-size-more-than-4kb-or-several-blocks